# how to count rows by first letter?

Tags: mysql, sql

a noob question here!

I wrote this query, but the "group by" is very stupid...
so, how can I correct this?

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS total,
    'x' as test
    FROM
contents
    WHERE name LIKE 'C%'
GROUP BY
    test
ORDER BY id ASC
```

different solutions and info about performances are welcome ( maybe using DISTINCT? )

thanks in advance!

Comment: yup, edited! the LIKE is a single letter

Comment: what is the output coming as?

Comment: LEFT(name,1) as letter... what about letters like "È" and GROUP BY? I use utf-8 and utf-8 and utf8_unicode_ci as collation... I want to use ascii alphabet then È should be considered "e"

Comment: i want a single row containing the total rows counted

Comment: You don't need group by to count records. Also, order by in aggregate query should be a column in group by list or aggregate function.

Comment: thanks everyone for answers... what about case sensitivity, letters like È? what I need to check to be sure of including letters like "È" in the letter "E" in the ascii alphabet? thanks

Comment: It will depend entirely on your collation. The best way to learn about these things is to experiment and then ask questions if you get stuck or have something specific to ask.

Comment: I will, thanks everyone for answers

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This should perform as well as any other option -

```
SELECT
    LEFT(name, 1) AS first_letter,
    COUNT(*) AS total
FROM contents
GROUP BY first_letter
```

If you want to run this query for a single letter at a time you can add the WHERE clause and drop the GROUP BY -

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
FROM contents
WHERE name LIKE 'a%'
```

Comment: I want to try to drop the group by, because i already know the letter... is there a way to group all the rows without a specific concept?

Comment: Just count(*) as in the second example

Comment: I like your first answer. It suggests that extract the data in select statement itself, so you can apply the group by condition on it.

Comment: I like the first answer for the reasons @aartist mentions plus the fact that it helps you QA/know your dataset - you see all possible starting characters. If I hardcoded "A", "B",... "Z" I would have never seen the records starting with non-alpha chars I didn't expect.

Comment: How to exclude words that starts with a number instead of a letter?

Answer (score 1):

Let's dissect your query:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS total,
    'x' as test     <-- Why?
    FROM            <-- Bad formatting.
contents
    WHERE name LIKE 'C%'
GROUP BY
    test            <-- Removing 'x' and the whole GROUP BY has the same effect.
ORDER BY id ASC     <-- The result only contains one row - nothing to sort.
```

So the query that returns one row with one field, containing the number of rows whose `name` begins with 'C' would look like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM contents
WHERE name LIKE 'C%'
```

Having an index whose **leading edge** is `name` would ensure good performance. To understand why, take a look at the [Anatomy of an SQL Index](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/anatomy).

Answer (score 0):

should give you everything in case you want it

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS total,
  test
FROM
 (SELECT substring(name,1,1) as test
 from contents) t
GROUP BY test
```